# Apache CustomLog doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2

I have this configuration ...

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/MyUrl1/*" p_myurl1
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myurl1_access.log common env=p_myurl1
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/MyUrl2/*" p_myurl2
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/myurl2_access.log common env=p_myurl2
```

But when the url ...

`www.mydomain.com/MyUrl2/blablabla.php` is typed, I want this logged to `myurl2_access.log` but it  logs to `access.log`. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you regexp should look like this: `"^/MyUrl2/.*$"` instead of this: `"^/MyUrl2/*"`

Comment: I'd leave out the $ - there's no need to specify that it should match until the end of the string. Otherwise I agree.